Unable to Remove Footer to Blogger Template Using Available Codes
kindly help me remove/hide footer credit in my blogger site template. i was able to hide it but still when someon hovers a mouse at the footer it shows a clickable sign and if someone clicks there it still redirects to the themes. I have placed an advert for free on my site that drives traffic to the original template. I do not like it being at the footer. The footer has this code
<![CDATA[<span class='copyright-text widget'>Design by - <a href='https://www.templatesite.com/' id='template id' rel='dofollow'>Template Site </a> |All Rights <a href='https://www.templatesite/' rel='dofollow'>Reserved</a></span>]]>

I tried using this method
<p>Copyright (c) 2021 <a href='https://www.yourdomain.com/'>YourSiteName</a> All Right Reseved</p>

<div style='font-size:1px; opacity:0;'>

//original content here

</div>

it worked by hiding but still the hidden links are clickable.
I want them not to be clickable.

So you want to remove the attribution, which is probably required, to use a template designed by someone else for free?

open source template

FYI: Open source doesn't entail something is "free" to use

It is open source without support. Support is available for a fee but not the template.
